# C# Parallelism / Multi-Threading / Multi-Tasking on multi core computers

Tags: c#, xml, multithreading, xslt, ssis

I am facing a problem, on which I already spent numerous hours but which I couldn't solve by now.

First of all a rough outline of the project at hand: I receive round about 170k complex XML files with varous sizes (from 5 KB to 10 MB), which have to be loaded into a SQL Server DB. Since they might slightly differ in structure (not all values / nodes are mandatory) I have a XSLT file which helps in "flattening" them and with this simplyfiy the process of loading them. Due to the massive amount of files (and data) we chose to use a rather good proportioned Server: 24 physical cores, virtualized to 48 cores, and round about 512 GB RAM.

Coming to the problem itself: since the XML Source in SSIS proved to be quite inperformant for this task, I decided to create a C# source component, which takes care of the loading and XSLT transforming of the XML files. However, in order to narrow performance issues down, I first created a console application in order to design and debug my approach. To speed up the described loading process, I planned to use multi threading in my source component: the idea was to load and transform numerous XML files parallely (since I loaded the XSLT as compiled transformation). So, basically what I planned to have as result in SSIS is a component, which loads maybe 50 or 100 files parallely and then sends the data to (currently) 10 outputs (for 10 tables).

The funny thing is: no matter what structure I use (Parallel.For, task factory, thread queue), my C# code will never create more than 24 threads (the number of physical cores).

To my general understanding: As far as I am informed, a TASK will require one core, whereas one core can have numerous THREADS...

So, what am I doing wrong? Is my general understanding of multi threading wrong?

Comment: `Parallel.For` is designed for CPU-bound operations, and therefore limits per default the number of threads to the number of physical cores (because more would be inefficient). This however can be overriden: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Without a good [mcve] showing exactly what you're doing, there's no way to answer your question. That said, the thread pool defaults to a number of threads equal to the number of cores, and will only add threads if your queued workers take too long. This is exactly what you want; if you have more threads than cores, they will fight with each other and slow things down.

Comment: Why do you want more thread running than you have cores? Aren't they fully utilized?

Comment: GWigWam no, I only reach something like 50%. The "virtual" cores (HyperThreading) stay idle...

Comment: If you have the time/energy to explore an alternative option, Saxon-EE provides multi-threaded XSLT processing "out of the box". For example, the collection() function which parses a collection of XML files processes them in parallel, and the xsl:result-document instruction which creates an output file spawns a new thread (or allocates one from a pool). I can't offer any guarantee that this will work better than your hand-written multi-threading code, but it would certainly be less effort to develop and maintain.